# Find all primes $p>2$ for which $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

> Find all primes $p>2$ for which $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

**Attempt.** Since $x^2+x+1$ is of degree 2, it is reducible iff it has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$. It has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ iff $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ has a root other than 1. The latter has a root other than $1$ iff $\mathbb{F}_p$ has elements of order $3$, which happens iff $3\mid |\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}|=p-1$, which happens iff $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$. So $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible iff $p\not \equiv 1\bmod3 $.

I am getting a different answer than my professor, who has $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$. If I am incorrect, were am I going wrong?

**Update.** Now I am unsure about my own reasoning. What if $1$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$? I don't know why I am considering roots of $x^2+x+1$ other than $1$ when $1$ can be a root.

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ is also reducible if $1$ is a multiple root of $x^3-1$.  This will be the case in $\mathbf{F}_3$, but not for any larger $p$ since $1^2+1+1=3\ne0$ unless $p=3$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems correct. For example, when $p = 7$, we have $$x^2 + x + 1 = (x - 2)(x+3),$$ so that the answer definitely can't be $p\equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $x^2+x+1=4^*((2x+1)^2+3)$, where $4^*$ is multiplicative inverse of $4$ modulo $p$. Now, the last expression can be made equal to 0 iff $-3$ is quadratic residue mod $p$, which you can use quadratic reciprocity to see that it happens iff $p\equiv 1\bmod 6$.

Comment: Why not writing $4^{-1}$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No real reason, I just wanted to make it clear that it's inverse mod $p$.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is a general result which says that for $p \nmid n$ the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $[p]$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$. Here, $n=3$, and the only non-generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^{\times}$ is $[1]$. Hence, $\Phi_3=X^2+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p \not\equiv 1 \bmod 3$.